# Getting Django to work with Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I'm new to python and django but wanted to start following some tutorials.  I installed python, then django, and then the pydev plugin for eclipse.  I created a new django project and tried running it.  In eclipse I set up a run configuration for manage.py with argument runserver and it said "Validating Models" but never said anything else.

I tried running via command line also but got some errors that I didn't see in eclipse:

```
C:\Users\JP\workspace\mysite\src\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x02851E30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 245,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 22, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 75, in <modul
e>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __getitem
__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 32, in load_back
end
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14
, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No mo
dule named MySQLdb
```

I assume it has something to do with my sql setup, but I'm not sure since it's a blank project and I haven't written any code yet.  I'm more concerned with why nothing showed up in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just starting myself.  Apparently there's a MySQLdb plugin (sorry if that's not the right term) that you need to use in addition to a standard MySQL install.  This is so Python can communicate with MySQL.

Comment: I got the plugin, no more errors in the command line but I still would like to be able to run from eclipse

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that you need to include the module in Eclipse System PYTHONPATH.

Go to Windows -> Preference -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python.

After Select your desired python interpreters (if you have a virtual env), include your MySQL egg and all your other dependencies in your library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have mysql installed. If you're only trying out django, you could use sqlite which ships with python. You can change the db backend in your settings.py file.